# Is there a way to omit exported functions bodies in Go?

Tags: go

Is there a way to avoid providing the implementation of external functions in Go? For example, in C you can compile the code into a static library and provide a header containing only the external API of your library for the user. In Go, however, even if I compile the code into a static library, the only way to use the library is by importing the package containing all the exported functions with their implementations.

So, the question is: In golang, is there a way to provide only an API to the user along with a binary file, like a static lib, and let the user use the API without providing him any kind of implementation code?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [Binary Only Packages](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages)? You always need at least a source stub though or the build tools. What is the actual goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I want